# How do I calculate current flow through a capacitor?

Tags: circuit-analysis, capacitor, current, basic, time-constant

Currently I've only worked out on the time constant and Vo(t).

Time constant = RC = (4500 + 1500)×(10 μF) = 0.015 s = 15 ms
Vo(t) = 24×(1500/{4500+1500))
I used the voltage divider rule in this case, as the capacitor and the resistors are in parallel, so I assumed both voltages are the same.

But with current, I can't seem to get any way around it as there is no resistance on the capacitor for me to use the Current Divider Rule. Do I have to use the exponential function formula for a charging capacitor to calculate it (E/R × e<sup>-t/T</sup>)?

Please advise.

[image]

Comment: After t=0, there is no resistor relating to `4500`. `Current Divider […] exponential …` You're overcomplicating it: instantaneously, a capacitor is like a voltage source. (I'm not fond of dropping units from equations.)

Comment: How should i proceed it then? I dont know if it's fully-charged or in its charging state.

Comment: The switch is depicted as *opened at t=0*: assume it has been closed infinitely before.

Comment: @Leewchaha You do know it. It is said in the homework assignment.

Comment: This is the thing. My lecture had confused all of us with questions like this. In the question, it meant that at t=0, the switch should already be opened. But in his example calculations during classes, the switches are closed at t = 0 and then only opens on t>0.

Comment: At t=0 (and at t>0) the switch is open and everything on the left side is gone. You are left with a charged capacitor and the two 3k resistors. (The capacitor voltage is dependent on the initial conditions - voltage divider).  Now recalculate as needed.

Comment: The description you included clearly says "opened at t=0s", (and the diagram shows the same).

Answer (score 1):

> so I assumed both voltages are the same.

This need not be an assumption. The 3kΩ resistors and the capacitor are in parallel so their voltages **must be** the same.

> But with current, I can't seem to get any way around it as there is no resistance on the capacitor

Redrawing the circuit will assist with visualizing. The voltage across the resistor must be the same as when the switch was closed because the voltage across a capacitor cannot change in an instant. Therefore the resistor current is the same as just before the switch is open.

Look closely at the diagram. R and C are in parallel, but now **they are also both in series.** While the switch was closed this claim could not be made.  What can be said about the currents in series connected elements?
The current through a capacitor can change instantly, including reversing the direction.
With this information you should be able to visualize the answer and complete the question.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRCBukm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

---

Let me capture a comment made by the OP.

> This is the thing. My lecture had confused all of us with questions like this. In the question, it meant that at t=0, the switch should already be opened. But in his example calculations during classes, the switches are closed at t = 0 and then only opens on t>0.

A common way to express the times at t=0 before an event or t=0 after an event is to use the following.

1. \$t=0^-\$ means as-if approaching t=0 from the left
2. \$t=0^+\$ means as-if approaching t=0 from the right

The question 3b is ambiguous. Before t=0, the capacitor current is 0A. After t=0 , it is something else. At t=0 the capacitor current is instantly changing. The current is indeterminate. Technically, this is the answer, but I infer that the question is implying that \$t=0^+\$.

> Do I have to use the exponential function formula for a charging capacitor to calculate it (E/R × e-t/T)?

No. You are dealing with the restricted time domain where \$0^- sec \leq t \leq 0^+ sec\$.

Answer (score -1):

You seem to have solved most of it, but I want to go through the whole lot, so I don't miss something.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fG8NZq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The first problem is that the network of resistors you showed us is complicated, and should really be simplified before you start thinking about the capacitor.

To make this simplification, the first thing to notice is the parallel pair of 3kΩ resistors, and I think you already spotted this. They are equivalent to a combined single resistance of

$$R_4 = \frac{3000 \times 3000}{3000 + 3000} = 1500\Omega $$

Now we have

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7RXD9.png)</sup>

Let's address the fact that the switch has been closed for a long time. The circuit has been like this for ages:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXXZXZ.png)</sup>

The capacitor has been charged to some voltage \$v_O(0s)\$, and you intuitively figured out that this is calculated to be the voltage at the junction of R1 and R4, as if the capacitor C1 were not there. That would be:

$$
\begin{aligned}
V_0 &= V_S \frac{R_4}{R_1 + R_4} \\ \\
&= 24 \frac{1500}{1500 + 4500} \\ \\
&= 6V \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

However, intuition is not enough. You must be able to show more rigourously why this is the case. For that I will refer you to [Thévenin's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9venin%27s_theorem). In this case we are able to replace the system consisting of R1, R4 and Vs (everything in the blue box), with a single voltage source \$V_{TH}\$ and single resistance \$R_{TH}\$.

We already calculated \$V_{TH}\$. It is the voltage that would be present across our equivalent circuit with no load attached. This would be the voltage across R4 with C1 absent, \$V_{TH}=6V\$.

For such a simple resistor voltage divider consisting of R1 and R4, \$R_{TH}\$ is the combined resistance of the two elements, as if they were connected in parallel:

$$
\begin{aligned}
R_{TH} &=\frac{R_1R_4}{R_1 + R_4} \\ \\
&= \frac{4500 \times 1500}{4500 + 1500} \\ \\
&= 1125\Omega \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

We replace R1, R4 and Vs with these calculated, equivalent elements:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flUk8X.png)</sup>

Using Thévenin equivalence, we've reduced the state of the circuit at time \$t < 0\$ down to a really simple system, and it's clear to see that just before we open the switch, the capacitor will have already charged to \$v_O(0) = 6V\$.

While we won't need the value of Rth, if one of the questions was "what is the time constant during initial charging, when \$t < 0\$?", you can see how this value would be useful.

For times \$t > 0\$, the circuit reverts to a prior form, where the battery and R1 are disconnected, leaving us with:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjLPSD.png)</sup>

Obviously the capacitor C1 will slowly discharge via R2, and the time constant will be:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\tau &= R_2 \times C_1 \\ \\
&= 1500 \times 10\times 10^{-6} \\ \\
&= 15ms
\end{aligned}
$$

All that remains to figure out is the current flowing when the switch is opened. Referring to the voltage and current labels in the last circuit, a simple application of Kirchhoff's Voltage Law will tell you that the voltage across the resistor is always the same as the voltage across the capacitor, and in this most trivial of applications of Kirchhoff's Current Law, the current through those two elements must also be the same.

We know the voltage across C1. Just after the switch opens, but before the capacitor has discharged at all, the capacitor applies 6V across R4. We also know that resistance, \$R_4=1500\Omega\$, so Ohm's law has our answer:

$$
\begin{aligned}
i(0) &= \frac{v_O(0)}{R_4} \\ \\
&= \frac{6V}{1.5k\Omega} \\ \\
&= 4mA
\end{aligned}
$$

The only time you need to employ the current divider rule, for a number of parallel-connected resistors, is when you don't know the voltage across them (see below left). In this case, though, you *do* know the voltage across them (on the right), and Ohm's law is immediately applicable:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLEZuF.png)</sup>

The only occasion you would have to use the capacitor discharge formula

$$
V = V_0e^{-\frac{t}{\tau}}
$$

is if you are asked for values *between* extremes of time, that is \$0<t<\infty\$. The expression will still yield the correct values for \$t=0\$ and \$t=\infty\$, but I think it is expected for you to know the value of \$e^0\$ and \$e^{-\infty}\$.

In this case, you are required only to evaluate voltage/current when \$t=0\$, for which \$e^{-\frac{t}{\tau}}= 1\$, no calculator needed.

Comment: The question asked was how to solve it; not to solve a homework for people.